# PyQt5, Letting Users resize the Widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have developing an app for various different purposes with PyQt5 and it is going very well. I know how to resize a widget (like QLineEidit, or QTextBrowser), however, I would like to know how I would be able to allow the USER to resize these widgets to their liking. I'm sorry that I do not provide any code, I have not fully started this project, I would like to know if what I am trying to do is possible. It would be really helpful if you provided a small chunk of code that does this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what *exactly* you are asking. You'd usually put your widgets in a layout, and then they resize when the user resizes the window.

You can also use a [QSplitter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html) so the user can resize two widgets relative to each other.

If you want the user to be able to resize any widgets in your window: I'm sure that'd be possible somehow, but I don't know how. However, that sounds like a rather bad UI to me.